# Google Sheet Script: Find row number of a cell in another sheet range by last row unique value then update columns of target row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets, one is a form responses, the other is with unique work codes.
When there is a form submit, I would like to copy and paste the time stamp of last work code in sheet "timedata" in column D where workcode matches. I also would like to do the same thing for the STATUS; copy the status from the answer and paste to sheet "timedata" in column E where the work code matches.
Here is my file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h2_tdStLOGSEtBToXKeb6FGCcVRhokyr7KRIv4uRgm4/edit?usp=sharing

I have a script as following but not sure how to continue;

```
function lastName() {
  var wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss1 = wb.getSheets()[0];
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var lr = ss1.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss1.getLastColumn();
  var dl = ss1.getRange(lr, lc);
  var cl = ss1.getRange(lr, lc - 1);
  var bl = ss1.getRange(lr, lc - 2);
  var al = ss1.getRange(lr, lc - 3);
  var ss2 = wb.getSheetByName('timedata');

  var mfns = ss2.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var i = 1;
  mfns.forEach(function(eachmfns) {
    if (cl.getValue() == mfns) {
    var dataRange = ss2.getRange(2, 1, 20, 5);
    var ss2 = wb.getSheetByName('timedata');
    dataRange = ss2.getRange(2 + i, 1 + 3);
    dataRange.setValue(al);
    i++; //to get the next row
}});
}
```

I would appreiate if anyone help me until this phase. If I can come until this point I believe I can calculate between the START time and STOP response time of a work so update TOTAL work time.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit SOLUTION**: The link to my file works, Form is not available but the script works when you run it. Please copy it your gDrive and try it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I have understood of your problem, I believe you are basically trying to put the data of the last element of sheet 1 in the matching workcode element in sheet 2. If this is not what you wanted or if I missunderstood your question please let me know and I will update this answer accordingly.

However, if I am right, this is the solution to your issue (details explained in the comments of this piece of code):

## Solution

```js
function makeItWork(){
  
  var wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss2 = wb.getSheetByName('timedata'); 
  var ss1 = wb.getSheets()[0];
  var lr = ss1.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss1.getLastColumn();
  
  // Get the desired values of the last added item including its workcode
  var timestamp = ss1.getRange(lr,1).getValue();
  var status = ss1.getRange(lr,4).getValue();
  var workcode = ss1.getRange(lr, 3).getValue();
  
  // Get the column values of workcode to then see which one matches with the last added item
  var columnValues = ss2.getRange('A:A').getValues(); 
  
  // Get values returns an Array with the elements nested in their own arrays,
  // we need to flat them to be able to do the array search later
  var searchValues = columnValues.flat();
  
  // Returns the row number of the adecuate workcode if it can match it to the one of the last element
  var searchResult = searchValues.indexOf(String(workcode)); 

  if(searchResult != -1){
  // If it found a match, add the data of the last element of sheet 1 in the right cells acording to the workcode match
  ss2.getRange(searchResult, 4).setValue(timestamp);
  ss2.getRange(searchResult, 5).setValue(status);
  }

}
```

I hope this has helped you, please let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something.

Comment: It worked! I just added `+1` to the last two lines. 
'ss2.getRange(searchResult+1, 4).setValue(timestamp);
ss2.getRange(searchResult+1, 5).setValue(status);'

Answer (score 0):

#### Required Reading:

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [2D array](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading)
- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services)

#### Notes:

- `getValues()` returns a two dimensional array indexed by rows and columns.(Array[0][1] = first row, second column)
- Avoiding `getValue*()` calls inside a loop can  greatly increase performance.
- Use batch operations

#### Sample script:

```
function lastName() {
  var wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss1 = wb.getSheets()[0];
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var lr = ss1.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss1.getLastColumn();
  const [al, bl, cl, dl] = ss1.getRange(lr, 1, 1, lc).getValues();
  var ss2 = wb.getSheetByName('timedata');

  var mfnsRng = ss2.getDataRange();
  const mfns = mfnsRng.getValues();//[[A1,B1..],[A2,B2..],[A3,B3..]...]
  mfns.forEach(function(row) {//row=currentRow=[A1,B1,C1..]
    if (cl === row[0]) {//row[0] = A1
      row[3] = al;//row[3] =Col D
      row[4] = dl;
    }
  });
  mfnsRng.setValues(mfns);//set modified values back
}
```